# What is the idiomatic way to share functions between files?

Tags: vim

I have a plugin function called InComment() stored in magic.vim *1

I would like to share it between two ftplugin files:

- ftplugin/c.vim
- ftplugin/python.vim

What is the idiomatic way to call InComment() function from my ftplugin files?

*1 plugin/magic.vim

```
function! s:InComment() " {{{
    let syn = s:SyntaxName(line('.'), col('.') - 1, 1)
    if syn =~? 'comment'
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    endif
endfunction "}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document referenced by Prince Goulash has everything you need.  To answer you specifically, you need to give the function a name based on the name of your plugin, like this:

```
function! magic#InComment() " {{{
    let syn = s:SyntaxName(line('.'), col('.') - 1, 1)
    if syn =~? 'comment'
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    endif
endfunction "}}}
```

Then you can call it from your plugin like this:

```
call magic#InComment()
```

The part before the # has to match the name of your plugin file.  This will also cause the plugin to be autoloaded when the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

I have just found this question while trying to answer it myself.

There is a Vim help section on [Writing Library Scripts](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#41.15), which looks like exactly what we need!

(Note: I haven't actually tried it yet. I will update this post if I run into problems.)